# How Do I Import Number Strings in Scientific Notation into a PSQL Table?

Tags: import, datatable, type-conversion, psql, scientific-notation

I am new to SQL and trying to upload data into tables from txt/csv files.

I am importing data from a text file that has strings in scientific notation. When I try to enter the data as an INTEGER type, I get the error that PostgreSQL cannot import the data as an INTEGER due to the character e+/-P :

ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type integer: "3.022300e+01"
CONTEXT:  COPY table6, line 1, column value: "3.022300e+01"

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUFaB.png)

How do I import this data as an integer?
I can find no data type in PostgreSQL that uses scientific notation.

I was able to upload the data to a table by altering the column to be a "text" type. I cannot convert the data type either?

ERROR:  column "value" cannot be cast automatically to type integer
HINT:  You might need to specify "USING value::integer".

What can I do to properly upload the data as an integer and not as a string?

I currently have used python to format the time columns into datetime Type formats, and can convert the data to integers with no scientific notation. I am planning to reupload the edited .txt file into my table, but I am will be working with larger data and anything to the order of >e10 gets very messy and hard to read if in expanded form.

Answer (score 0):

The two data types that offer themselves are `numeric' and 'double precision':

```
SELECT '1e10'::numeric, '1e10'::double precision;

   numeric   │   float8    
═════════════╪═════════════
 10000000000 │ 10000000000
(1 row)
```

You could also use `real`, but that's a bad choice because of its low precision.